# What Atlassian Bamboo task types are available for Ruby on Rails projects?

Tags: bamboo

I'm still confused with configuring a task, is every task type for every programming language different? For example, I am using Ruby on Rails, but I don't know which task type enables me to build a respective project.

Answer (score 0):

> is every task type for every programming language are different

Not necessarily, but the various [build in](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Configuring+tasks) and [3rd party](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?application=bamboo&category=Tasks&cost=&hosting=&marketingLabel=&q=tasks) Tasks available for [Atlassian Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/de/software/bamboo) are usually tailored for a specific use case, which for build tasks is often closely related to a specific programming language indeed (there are also tasks for completely different topics, e.g. our [Tasks for AWS](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/net.utoolity.atlassian.bamboo.tasks-for-aws) enables you to *provision and operate Amazon Web Services resources from Bamboo build and deployment projects*).

- You can read more about the related concepts in [Jobs and tasks](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Jobs+and+tasks) - in particular, a task is defined as:

  - *Is a small discrete unit of work, such as source code checkout, executing a Maven goal, running a script, or parsing test results.*
  - *Is run sequentially within a job on a Bamboo working directory.*

The task you are probably looking for is Mark Wolfe's great [Bamboo Ruby Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/au.id.wolfe.bamboo.rake-bamboo-plugin) (GitHub: [rake-bamboo-plugin](https://github.com/wolfeidau/rake-bamboo-plugin/)), which *enables you to run ruby tasks during a build in Bamboo* and includes tasks for the most prevalent Ruby build and automation tools:

- [Bundler](http://bundler.io/)
- [Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/)
- [Capistrano](http://www.capistranorb.com/)

Please note that there's also the [Bamboozled Ruby Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.alienfast.bamboozled.ruby.bamboozled-ruby-plugin), which is a fork from Mark's rake-bamboo-plugin version 2.1 with the goal to *move the plugin forward in a specific way* - I haven't used it so far, thus can't comment on the differences, please refer to their [GitHub: bamboozled-ruby-plugin](https://github.com/alienfast/bamboozled-ruby-plugin) for details.